# ESP32-CAM DMA PROBLEM with upython

Tags: esp32

I'm running micropython_camera_feeeb5ea3_esp32_idf4_4.bin & the camera won't initialise if I've previously used https via urequests

```
E (14790) cam_hal: cam_dma_config(296): DMA buffer 32768 Byte malloc failed, the current largest free block:20992 Byte E (14800) cam_hal: cam_config(364): cam_dma_config failed
```

If I've previously used http via urequests all OK so I figure it's something to do with ssl (http doesn't use ssl). I'd prefer to stick with https but can't figure out a way to clean up ram after it, gc.collect() isn't helping.

Comment: Have you tried initialising the camera before making the request? Have you checked available memory (to see if it’s a problem of availability or fragmentation of free memory)? Do you download anything big? Have you tried `fb_location=camera.PSRAM` As argument to the camera init?

Comment: I have, but then I have to deinit it otherwise urequests throws an enomem error. From '32768 Byte malloc failed, the current largest free block:20992' I assume it's a fragmentation issue. I tried changing camera.init(0, format=camera.JPEG) to camera.init(0, fb_location=camera.PSRAM, format=camera.JPEG) but it didn't help. I don't download anything big.  Is there some way to deinit or otherwise undo what ssl has done to ram?

Comment: From the message alone it’s difficult to say if it’s fragmentation or actual available memory. Check out what gc.mem_free() says (possibly at different points of your script, to see which calls use what).

Comment: Well that's weird camera initialisation after ssl use is working now & I haven't changed anything. Likewise no enomem error from urequests if I use the camera first. I should be pleased, but it's hard to be  without a logical explanation.

Comment: If you haven’t changed anything on your side, it could be related to changes in the certificates on the server but that makes it fragile in case those change again in the other direction.

Comment: One of the things I tried, when the board was running out of memory, was to swap from a .py file to a .mpy file which saved me 40k-13k=27k. I was surprised when this didn't fix the problem since the the 'largest free block' error msg more or less hinted that the memory shortage was 33k-21k=12k. Can you explain a bit more about how server certificate changes impact memory use in the ESP32?